# Trying to go to next line in an entry in a cell

Tags: tables, line-breaking, cv

I've recently decided to use latex to make my CV. I've therefore used an overleaf template:

https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/modernfancycv/bkjntytgpcmq

The last thing I want to do now is to gain a bit of space. I would like the dates (in the education and work experience sections) to go into two lines instead of one.
Instead of having:

XXXX - XXXX

I would like to have

XXXX -
XXXX

The thing is that in the .cls, the author of this template used this:

```
\RequirePackage{soul}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\newenvironment{entrylist}{%
    \vspace{-0.8mm}
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ll}
}{%
  \end{tabular*}
}
\renewcommand{\bfseries}{\headingfont\color{headercolor}}
\newcommand{\entry}[5]{%
    \fontsize{9.4pt}{5cm}\selectfont\addfontfeature{Color=darkergray}#1&\parbox[t]{13.6cm}{%
    \fontsize{11.4pt}{5cm}\selectfont\textbf{#2}%
    \textbf{\selectfont\addfontfeature{Color=darkergray}#3}%
    \hspace{2mm}%
    {\footnotesize\addfontfeature{Color=seafoamgreen} #4}\vspace{1mm}\\%
    \normalsize#5%
  }\\}
```

And in the .tex :

```
\section{EDUCATION}
\begin{entrylist}
 
   \entry
    {March, 2005\enspace}
    {Advanced Training | }{\small{internal}}
    {\normalsize\textbf{\color{ipsgreen}\faMapMarker\space International Parcel Service (IPS)}}
    {\jobspace
    \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*, itemsep = 0.1em]
    \item Completed the IPS aptitude test for aspiring managerial staff
    \item Subsequently decided to keep pursuing his passion for driving and delivering instead\\
    \end{itemize}}
\end{entrylist}
```

I've tried different things like \newline or \break but it seems to me that tabular* and entrylist are not the best things to work with here.

Therefore I would need your advice on how to proceed :)

Best,

Answer (score 1):

You can to put the `#1` parameter of `\entry` into a `parbox` and adjust the position of the date to your liking.

```
\parbox[position][height][inner-pos]{width}{text}
```

[image: out]

This is a small MWE. I guess you can edit the .cls and create your class.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}

\newenvironment{entrylist}{%
    \vspace{-0.8mm}
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ll}}
    {\end{tabular*}
}

%%  \parbox[position][height][inner-pos]{width}{text} <<<<<<<
\newcommand{\entry}[5]{%
\parbox[t][1cm][b]{2.5cm}{\fontsize{9.4pt}{5cm}\selectfont\addfontfeature{Color=gray}#1}&\parbox[t]{13.6cm}{%
        \fontsize{11.4pt}{5cm}\selectfont\textbf{#2}%
        \textbf{\selectfont\addfontfeature{Color=gray}#3}%
        \hspace{2mm}%
        {\footnotesize\addfontfeature{Color=green} #4}\vspace{1mm}\\%
        \normalsize#5%
    }\\}

\newcommand{\jobspace}{\vspace*{-4.2mm}}

\begin{document}
    
    \section{EDUCATION}
    
    \begin{entrylist}       
        \entry
        {March, 2005\enspace}
        {Advanced Training | }{\small{internal}}
        {\normalsize\textbf{\color{green}\space International Parcel Service (IPS)}}
        {\jobspace
            \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*, itemsep = 0.1em]
                \item Completed the IPS aptitude test for aspiring managerial staff
                \item Subsequently decided to keep pursuing his passion for driving and delivering instead\\
        \end{itemize}
    }
      \entry
        {1988\,-\,1991\enspace}
        {Security Guard  | }{\small Nightclub \& Bar}
        {\normalsize\textbf{\color{green}\space Sour Polly, Queens, NY}}
        {\jobspace
        \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*, itemsep = 0.1em]
        \item Providing rigorous access control of costumers
        \item Making difficult and critical entry decisions
        \item Keeping the customers safe and entertained\\
        \end{itemize}
        }

    \end{entrylist} 
    
\end{document
```

I added (before `\begin{document}`) to the Overleaf template

```
\renewcommand{\entry}[5]{%
\parbox[t][1cm][b]{2.5cm}{\fontsize{9.4pt}{5cm}\selectfont\addfontfeature{Color=gray}#1}&\parbox[t]{13.6cm}{%
        \fontsize{11.4pt}{5cm}\selectfont\textbf{#2}%
        \textbf{\selectfont\addfontfeature{Color=gray}#3}%
        \hspace{2mm}%
        {\footnotesize\addfontfeature{Color=green} #4}\vspace{1mm}\\%
        \normalsize#5%
    }\\}
```

and I got

[image: over]